# Can Visual Studio track the "size" or "severity" of my changes in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, team-foundation-server

I'm working on a sizeable project using VS2012 and TFS (also 2012, I think - I didn't set up the server). A lot of my recent tasks have required making very small changes to a lot of files, so I'm quite used to seeing a lot of items in my Pending Changes list. Is there a way to have VS and/or TFS track how much has been changed and let me know when the differences are becoming significant? Similarly, is there a way to quickly highlight where the major changes are when you get the latest version from TFS? It'd really help with tracking down where certain changes have been made without having to go through and compare every file - the difference highlighting tool might be nice, but when you have to use it on a dozen files to find the block you're looking for, you start to wonder if there's a faster way...

Comment: I am not sure how you expect software to determine if changes are significant or not.  There are tools that will highlight the differences between specific changes or list all recent changes but to define if a change is significant is best left to manual task.

Comment: A simple count of number of lines/characters changed would suffice, expressed either as a raw number or as a percentage of the total for that file. There are other ways, using things like difference in cyclomatic complexity before/after the change, but that's probably overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Code Churn reports:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jampick/tfs-2010-code-churn-report-getting-additional-detail)

they should tell you what (generally) and how much has changed over time.